# iOS keychain wrapper class Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting below error when I am trying to save value in keychain.

```
SYKeychain *keychainsave = [[SYKeychain alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"keyChainSample11" accessGroup:nil];


[keychainsave setObject:txtUserName.text forKey:(__bridge id )kSecAttrAccount];
```

I used keychainitemwrapper class i want to make it for ARC based without setting flag -fno-objc-arc in compile header.

is any one have idea how i can achieve this.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't update the Keychain Item.'
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do like this,

```
SYKeychain *keychainsave = [[SYKeychain alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"keyChainSample11" accessGroup:nil];

[keychainsave setObject:txtUserName.text forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecAttrAccount];
```